# SQL Select where first value and last value of daterange

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to SQL queries and I need to make a join starting from this query:

```
SELECT b.Name, a.*
FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.VId = b.Id
WHERE  b.SId = 100
       AND a.Day >= '2016-05-05'
       AND a.Day < '2016-05-09';
```

and adding 2 more columns to the first selected data (SCap and ECap from table c).
From what I've tried my code looks like this:

```
    SELECT b.Name,a.*,
       c.MaxDay,
       c.Cap,
FROM   a INNER JOIN b
       ON a.VId = b.Id
       INNER JOIN
       (SELECT   VId,
                 MAX(TimestampLocal) AS MaxDay,
                 CAST (TimestampLocal AS DATE) AS Day,
                 Cap,
        FROM Info
        GROUP BY VId, 
                 CAST (TimestampLocal AS DATE), 
                     Cap) AS c
       ON a.VId = c.VId
          AND a.Day = c.Day
WHERE  b.SId = 33
       AND a.Day >= '2016-05-05'
       AND a.Day < '2016-05-09';
```

But I get more rows than needed.

I need the earliest and the latest TimestampLocal for a given vehicle in a daterange. That would come from two records in Info, and each would have its proper values for Cap. 
For example:
I have two Names with values inside table Info for 2 days (Name 1) and only one day for Name 2:

```
- Day 1 2016-05-07:
    - Name 1: Values at 2:45, 10:10 and 3.10
    - Name 2: Values at 5:13 and 8:22
- Day 2 2016-05-09:
    - Name 1: Values at 4:13, 6:15 and 9:20
```

I need to display (if I select daterange: `2016-05-05` to `2016-05-09`) for Name 1 for SCap the value from 2016-05-07 from 2:45 and for ECap the value from 2016-05-09 from 9:20 and for Name 2 for SCap the value from 2016-05-07 from 5:13 and for ECap the value from 2016-05-07 from 8:22. This should be displayed in 2 lines.

Is there a way I can add those 2 columns into my query without adding more rows for the same Name?

EDIT! 
Table a I have:

```
VId   | Day
5251  | 05/09/2016
5382  | 05/09/2016
```

Table b:

```
Id    | Name
5251  | N1
5382  | N2
```

Table Info:

```
VId   | TimestampLocal                      |  Cap
5251  | 2016-05-09 11:33:46.2000000 +03:00  |   0
5251  | 2016-05-09 11:37:11.4000000 +03:00  |   7
5251  | 2016-05-09 11:38:11.4000000 +03:00  |   4
5251  | 2016-05-09 11:39:11.7000000 +03:00  |   2
5382  | 2016-05-09 09:30:56.6000000 -04:00  |   5
5382  | 2016-05-09 09:31:56.6000000 -04:00  |   3
```

And I need to display - if I select a daterange from `2016-05-03` to `2016-05-10`:

```
Id    | Name | SCap | ECap
5251  | N1   | 0    | 2
5382  | N2   | 5    | 3
```

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: @vkp - I've updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my query after some further investigations and here is what I managed to do:

```
SELECT      b.Id,
            b.Name,
            c.S_Time,
            c.E_Time,
            s.Cap AS S_Cap,
            e.Capa AS E_Cap,
FROM        b
INNER JOIN   (SELECT  VId,
                     MIN(TimestampLocal) AS S_Time,
                     MAX(TimestampLocal) AS E_Time
            FROM     Info
            where CAST (TimestampLocal AS DATE) >='2016-04-05'
            and CAST (TimestampLocal AS DATE) <'2016-05-10'
            GROUP BY VId
            ) AS c
        ON  b.Id = c.VId
INNER JOIN   Info AS s
        ON  s.VId = c.VId
        AND s.TimestampLocal = c.S_Time
INNER JOIN   Info AS e
        ON  e.Vd = c.VId
        AND e.TimestampLocal = c.E_Time
WHERE   b.SId = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CTE` with `ROW_NUMBER` in order to retrieve the two records:

```
;WITH Info_CTE AS (
   SELECT   VId,            
            CAST (TimestampLocal AS DATE) AS Day,
            Cap,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VId 
                               ORDER BY TimestampLocal) AS rn1,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VId 
                               ORDER BY TimestampLocal DESC) AS rn2
   FROM Info
)
SELECT b.Name,
       a.*,
       c.Day,
       c.Cap
FROM  a 
INNER JOIN b ON a.VId = b.Id
INNER JOIN Info_CTE AS c ON a.VId = c.VId AND 
                            a.Day = c.Day AND
                            1 IN (c.rn1, c.rn2)
WHERE  b.SId = 33
       AND a.Day >= '2016-05-05'
       AND a.Day < '2016-05-09';
```

If you want `ECap` and `SCap` as separate columns then instead of

```
c.Cap
```

you can use:

```
CASE WHEN c.rn1 = 1 THEN c.Cap END AS ECap,
CASE WHEN c.rn2 = 1 THEN c.Cap END AS SCap
```

Comment: I don't get anything when I'm trying to run this code :(

Answer (score 0):

First, get the max and min timestamp for each id for a given date. Then join it twice, once with the max timestamp value and then with the min timestamp value for each id to tblinfo,to get the start and end cap values for those rows.

Add a `where` clause with a date filter to filter for specific days.

[Sample demo](http://rextester.com/NNAN4073)

```
with maxandmin as 
(select vid
        ,max(timestamplocal) maxtime
        ,min(timestamplocal) mintime
 from tblinfo
 group by vid,cast(timestamplocal as date))
select m.vid,b.name,i1.cap as Scap,i2.cap as Ecap
from maxandmin m 
join tblinfo i1 on m.vid=i1.vid and m.mintime = i1.timestamplocal
join tblinfo i2 on m.vid=i2.vid and m.maxtime = i2.timestamplocal
join tableb b on b.id=m.vid
```

Comment: it had to be changed to `i`.

Comment: see if the edited version works. had to change the query.

Comment: I've tried to run it for 2 different names and: I get 6 rows instead of just 2 and it's running very slow :(

Comment: i guess it is because you get the start and end time for each day.add the date column in the output to check.as per the questin that is what u needed.